# Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, intellisense

IntelliSense stoped working. There is a window appears when I try to go to definition or when I create a project, with message:

An error occured while creating or opening the C++ browsing database file 'file path'. IntelliSense and browsing information will not be available for C++ projects.
Ensure that Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is installed and that no other applications are accessing the file. If this problem persists, delete the file and reopen the solution.

Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is installed on my computer, and I tryed reinstall it and its different versions and service packs many-many times.

Also I've tryed to create a project on different local disks and use fallback location, but all this didn't help.

Maybe the problem will dissapear, when I will intall updates, but I can't! When I'm launching update setup, I getj an error: "Microsoft .NET Framework required for Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 setup". But I have latest version of Microsoft .NET Framework installed on my computer.

I have Windows 7 Professional with all latest updates installed.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried just deleting the sdf files and allowing Visual Studio to recreate them

Comment: Yes, I have. And also when I create new project, sdf file doesn't created at all.

Comment: The only time I ever get this is when I open the same solution in multiple instances of VS simultaneously. Fire up procexp and see if there is a rogue devenv hanging on to your solution.

Comment: Good assumption, but it can't help. I've killed all suspicious processes, and also I rebooted system many times after this problem appeared.

Comment: Have you tried doing _Programs and Features_ -> _Microsoft Visual Studio [Your Version]_ -> _Change_ -> _Repair_?

Comment: Yes, I have, and I get the second problem: "Microsoft .NET Framework required for Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Setup". I have the latest .NET Framework 4.5.1, and this message appeares when I try to repair, install vs, or install update, or install vs2013 and so on.

Comment: I think the only way for me is to reinstall windows, lol

Answer (score 0):

Go to TOOLS / Options / Text Editor / C++ / Advanced / Always use fallback location = True.